# Prevent leaving page for everything but certain things on the page

Tags: jquery

I've ready many SO questions on this and have not found one specific to my needs.

I want a confirmation box to pop up when someone is attempting to leave a page unless it i a specific reason.

```
//This currently blocks everything even legitimate ways I'm ok with them leaving
// Warning
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
            return "Any changes will be lost";
        });
```

I don't want this message to show if any of these specific links are clicked.  I could have one link on a page or hundreds.

```
<a href="/Quote/PlanDetails?planID=6435&amp;rateID=689142" class="button button-3d button-mini button-rounded button-green nomargin">Select</a>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: That is a link styled as a button, not a button. However, you can easily toggle a variable on button click and not call the confirm based off that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a class on click that you can then check for later. Something simple should work

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('check-leave');
});
```

Then just make a check to see if any elements have this class with your existing code

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if($('.button').hasClass('check-leave')){
        return "Any changes will be lost";
    } else {
        //continue
    }
});
```

Sample fiddle (links are set to have red text when the 'check-leave' class is active)

https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/vx7uyfyf/1/